# Question about the efficiency of two codes that look similar

Tags: python, algorithm

The followings are the question Beautiful Arrangement(LeetCode 526) and two pieces of codes to the question. code 1 and code 2 look the same to me but I don't understand why code 1 takes much more time than code 2. Can somebody help me figure out the reason? Thanks in advance!

Question:
Suppose you have N integers from 1 to N. We define a beautiful arrangement as an array that is constructed by these N numbers successfully if one of the following is true for the ith position (1 <= i <= N) in this array:

The number at the ith position is divisible by i.
i is divisible by the number at the ith position.

Now given N, how many beautiful arrangements can you construct?

code 1:

```
def countArrangement(self, N: int) -> int:

    def dfs(cur,N,seen):
        if cur==N:
            return 1
        res = 0
        for i in seen:
            if (cur+1)%i==0 or i%(cur+1)==0:
                res += dfs(cur+1,N,seen-{i})
        return res
    seen = set(range(1,N+1))
    return dfs(0,N,seen)
```

code 2:

```
def countArrangement(self, N: int) -> int:

def count(i,X):
    if i==1: return 1
    return sum(count(i-1,X-{x}) for x in X if i%x==0 or x%i==0)
return count(N,set(range(1,N+1)))
```

Comment: It's not about your code but time calculation on LeetCode doesn't seem working correctly.

Comment: @sashaaero Do you mean that their time complexities are the same so technically they should run at the same time?

Comment: I mean that if you run same code several times you'll see that it gives different results. For me code1 doesn't seem to be slower, but i don't know which tests did you get.
Maybe some branch prediction or inner language optimizations also affect.

Comment: @Victor.L Time complexities being equivalent *does not* imply that they should run in the same time at all. This is a key point you need to understand about time complexity.